# Return view in controller AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

How can I return a view and display it through the controller in AdonisJs

```
'use strict'

class PostController {

  index(){
    return view.render('welcome')
  }

}

module.exports = PostController
```

report this error:

```
ReferenceError
view is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `response.send(view.render('<your_view>'))`

Something like:

```js
...
index({ response, view }){ // Get objects from HTTP Context
  return response.send(view.render('welcome'))
}
```

[HTTP Context documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request-lifecycle#_http_context)

[Official forum answer](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/issues-with-exception-handling-in-v4-1/751/12)

Answer (score 1):

i know its late but this worked for me.

```
'use strict'

class PostController {

  async index({request,response,view}){
    return view.render('welcome')
  }

}

module.exports = PostController
```